# I am facing problems with a procedure that uses dictionary

Tags: python, function

I want to create a procedure called WriteEmail() that takes a dictionary as an argument. This
dictionary should have username as key values ​​and email suffix as values. The function should iterate through all the elements in the dictionary and call on the function
createEmail() on each user, and print the result.

The createEmail() function looks like this:

```
def createEmail(username, email_suffix): 
     
    return(username+ "@" + email_suffix) 

username = input ("Skriv inn din brukernavn: ") 
email_suffix= input ("Skriv inn din epost suffix: ")  

print(createEmail(username, email_suffix))
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I got stuck, maybe I am overthinking it.

This is what I tried:

```
def printOutemails(dict): 
    for key in dict:
        dict[key] 
        print(key + "@" + dict[key])   
print(printOutemails(dict))
```

tested with:
dict = {"olan":"fun.com","karin":"fun.com"}

my output:
olan@fun.com
karin@fun.com

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is wrong (extra set of parentheses). It needs to read:

```
def createEmail(username, email_suffix):
```

Comment: Good to hear. You can accept the answer if the problem was solved.